# Possibility that objects are not the same after serialization/deserialization

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, cereal

<sub>(This question is not very clear, maybe not appropriate. I pondered a lot, but in the end, I thought it's better to get any advice than to ask nothing.)</sub>

I tried to serialize/deserialize a custom struct, using the 'cereal' library, but I found that some part of the deserialized object is not the same as the original object.

Here is the process I went through:
(Windows, MSVC, 'Release' configuration(optimization ON))

1. Read a text file and make an object(`std::unordered_map`) that contains different types of `std::vector<T>`s. The current timestamp is also recorded in the object.
2. Serialize the object and save it as a binary file, using the cereal library. - [file1]
3. Repeat 1. (read text and make an object, writing the current timestamp - so the timestamps are different) - [object1]
4. Deserialize the [file1] and compare it with [object1], by `obj1.vector1 == obj2.vector1`.

I thought only the vector that contains the timestamp would be different and all the other vectors would be the same, **but** some vectors were not the same.

What I tried:

1. Change `std::unordered_map` to `std::map`. -> Result doesn't change.
2. Run the program with debug mode. -> Result changes, but the two objects are still different.
3. Fix the value of the timestamps. -> the two objects become the same.

=> Only the result of 3. is what I expected.
I don't understand how this can happen. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

---

Below are some codes for describing what was done.

The struct contains some vectors, such as:

```
// not exactly the same struct that I used, but you get the idea..
struct MyStruct{
    std::vector<uint64_t> timestamps;
    std::vector<int> scores;
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    //...
}
```

(I `push_back`ed the current timestamp in microseconds into the `timestamps` vector.)

Code used for serializing the object into a binary file using a standard way the library suggests:

```
{
    std::ofstream ofsb{ path, std::ios_base::binary };
    cereal::BinaryOutputArchive oab(ofsb); 
    oab(myObject_to_binary);
}
```

Code for deserialization, using the same 'cereal' library:

```
{
    std::ifstream ifsb{ path, std::ios_base::binary };
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iab(ifsb);
    iab(myObject_from_binary);
}
```

Comment: Code changing behaviour in release mode indicates the presence of undefined behaviour. Please show a [mre]

Comment: I would start with a simpler data structure to see if that works.  Then work your way up.

Comment: @AlanBirtles My mistake, I found the two objects were still different even with debug mode(question modified). But anyway the results between release mode and debug mode are different, so that indicates the presence of undefined behavior, right? I'll try to make a minimal reproducible example. Thanks a lot.